# Close IE after download file by direct link

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, hyperlink, download

I use this code to download file from a direct download link via IE. However I stuck when it run to line
IE.quit, run time error 462: the remote sever machine does not exist. Here my code:

```
Sub Download ()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim a, l As Integer
Sheet3.Select
Range("A1").Select
l = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
For a = 1 To l
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate Cells(a, 2)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
Application.SendKeys "%{S}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
IE.Quit
IE = Nothing
Next a
End Sub
```

Please help me to solve this. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you create the `IE` object outside the loop but release the `IE` object in the loop. You release it in the loop so when it loops for the second time, you can't use it anymore. You can release `IE` after the loop is finished. Besides, there should be a `Set` before `IE = Nothing`.

The code should be like below:

```
Sub Download()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim a, l As Integer
Sheet2.Select
Range("A1").Select
l = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
For a = 1 To l
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate Cells(a, 2)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
Application.SendKeys "%{S}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
Next a
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```